# No module named 'pycaret

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, visual-studio-code, pycaret

I am getting this error in my VSCODE:

```
No module named 'pycaret
```

my query is this:

```
from pycaret.classification import *
```

I have installed pycaret, may I know how can I solve this error?

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your system, and you installed pycaret for the wrong version.

Comment: Please follow this [installation tutorial](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation) and have a try.

Comment: please check in cmd whether pycaret is installed or not using !pip freeze command

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install pycaret in a clean python environment. Then enable the python environment before trying to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code chunk on your Visual studio Code IDE's terminal ?

```
pip install pycaret --user
```

I had similiar experience like yours while i have anaconda environment, i also have python's path. So using this will not clear way to do but if you stuck just use it and continue your journey !

If you using anaconda environment use this on anaconda prompt

```
conda install -c conda-forge pycaret
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, and solved it this way:

I installed pycaret :

```
!pip install pycaret
```

I installed Jinja2:

```
!pip install Jinja2
```

Lastly installed markupsafe (dependency resolver) :

```
!pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Then Restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Two reminders:**

1. If you are using **anaconda** (that is, if you are using the `conda` command for installations), avoid using `pip` as much as possible, that is, for installations, use the `conda` command as much as possible instead of `pip`.
2. For creating a virtual environment:

   a) You can use python's `venv` command:

   `python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`

   [docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

   b) Or you can use conda:
   `conda create --name env_name python=3.7`

   This will create a virtual environment with the name 'env_name' whis has python 3.7.

   [fritz.ai/creating-python-virtual-environments-with-conda-why-and-how/](https://fritz.ai/creating-python-virtual-environments-with-conda-why-and-how/)